# I do not understand, are Neyman-Pearson rule and Sequential Probability Ratio Test refers to the same thing?

Tags: probability, bayesian, sequential-analysis

In Bayesian statistics, I remember to Neyman Pearson rule, in which, based on a threshold value, we have the option of reject to make a decision: decision option.

Now, I wonder if it is the same as the Sequential Probability Ratio Test (SPRT), or they have the same idea but different methods or different application areas, or simply how they differ?

Comment: You've got it wrong, Neyman-Pearson is used in frequentist statistics.

Comment: ... as is the  Sequential Probability Ratio Test, a major distinction between them being the *sequential* in the latter